# Java + Spring Boot + REST security question

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

I am new to Java. I'm creating a REST api using Spring Boot + OAuth2 authentication + Swagger.

What I'd like to do is obviously have the swagger page allow anonymous access and the /token/oauth end point requires basic authentication.

For my controllers, I'm set up to use @PreAuthorize, generally with #oauth2.hasScope('xxx'). I'd like to POTENTIALLY have get methods that allow anonymous GETs in the same controller as locked down methods.

So... what I've done is in ResourceServerConfig have the line as:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").permitAll();
```

So basically, everything is allowed and then the @PreAuthorize overrides anything I want to protect.

I'd rather define which methods are locked down in the controllers with the PreAuthorize then maintain a giant ant matcher list of anonymous paths. Seems cleaner to me.

This is all working as expected. Any method that does NOT have @PreAuthorize is open and methods that DO have @PreAuthorize require authentication.

Is there anything dangerous about the ("/*").permitAll()? As I'm new to Java, I'm not sure if this is opening up any holes? Seems like there are some "hidden" endpoints as I had to add a filter to swagger config: RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.xxx.yyy") to only show my actual APIs.

Just trying to understand any ramifications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@SledgeHammer, instead of keeping it open "/", handle it in the controller to redirect it to somewhere and instead of keeping "/" to permitAll, so apply it to specific url pattern.

Comment: What I mean is, I have /customers/m1 which is locked down w/ PreAuthorize and /customers/m2 which is open (not sure if I will do that in the real world, more for building a "shell")… just concerned if /* permitAll is opening up anything it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with specific like /customers/m1 you can secure and /customers/m2 you can make permitAll but avoid "/*" to permitAll as this access to all.

Comment: yes, but then I have to decorate with PreAuthorize AND maintain a list of public end-points no? With /* I only need to have PreAuthorize.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use  ("/*").permitAll() as it always evaluates to true
Example, "denyAll" will deny access to all of the matching Messages; "permitAll" will grant access to all of the matching  so no use to implement security if you permitAll.

- https://www.slideshare.net/SpringCentral/application-security-pitfallshandout
- https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/06/spring-security-misconfiguration.html
- https://spring.io/blog/2014/04/22/springone2gx-2013-replay-application-security-pitfalls
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A6-Security_Misconfiguration

Comment: I think you missed a key point in my question :). I want to be able to control security at the controller with @PreAuthorize. What if /customers/m1 has pre-authorize and /customers/m2 does NOT? Then /customers/m2 should be public. Now, it seems like it's almost the same either way. Make everything private and list all public points or make everything public and list all private points. Basically without the /*, I have no way of making an endpoint public with specifying it in the list? I.e. swagger, etc? Is there any way to annotate similar to @PreAuthorize?

Comment: By using /*, it makes everything public by default, and then the @PreAuthorize makes private private, no? When I set up swagger, it exposes "hidden" controllers by default which has me concerned.

Comment: Instedof /* you can use                                                                       .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()
or      .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll() here is good examle
https://github.com/vaquarkhan/jwt-spring-security-demo

Comment: I understand what you are saying :). What I am asking is this way I have to specifically list out all public endpoints PLUS use PreAuthorize on the private ones to define scope. If I have a controller that has private AND public that list will grow huge.